# Using manyConsole to creating a default argument with no flags but still have commands that require flags

Tags: c#, manyconsole

I just found manyConsole for commandline parsing and believe that it can meet my requirements for a Windows console app in my project except for one thing. Can I have manyConsole parse the commandline so that I have the following functionality

```
myapp.exe C:\somedirectory\somefile.ext -v 10.00
```

where file path would be required but not preceeded by a flag or command but each argument after would require a flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not dispatching to different commands, Mono.Options would be a more direct match.  Both will handle the flagged options then give you a list of unhandled options (which in your case would be the path at the beginning.)  Either will work.  You might prefer many console still as it will help with error/help responses.

Comment: Are there any examples of this anywhere on your NuGet page?

Comment: There might be something in https://github.com/fschwiet/ManyConsole/tree/master/SampleConsole

Comment: Thank you Frank. Just after I accepted your answer and sent out the question reply, I started to look at your examples on github.